# .NET Remoting: How to active (remote) object on the server right away?

Tags: .net, remoting

I have a remote object hosted in a Window Service which may take a little time to initialize. The problem is that the first client request mostly fails becuase it takes too long, but the following requests succeed. I'm wondering if there is a way to make the remote object created right away when service starts up. Here is the code in service's OnStart():

```
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new HttpChannel(8080), false);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(MyService), "MyService", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your service's `OnStart` spawn a process that does a null transaction--something innocuous that has no effect other than to force creation of the remote object.

Another thing you could do is have the startup processing do all the expensive initialization and save the result in some object.  Initialization of the remote object would then just be a matter of initializing a reference to that pre-constructed object.  I guess you could say then that the remote object serves as a proxy to the methods exposed by the object that you constructed at startup time.

As I recall (it's been a while since I played with remoting, so I could be wrong), it's not possible for the service itself to act as a client and make a call to initialize the remote object.

Comment: @miliu: Which tip did you use? Did you spawn a process to do the initialization, or did you do the expensive part of the initialization in `OnStart`?

Comment: I used your suggestion in the second paragraph: I made my remote object singleton (luckily, this is okay in my case) and called it right after the server starts.